# MR_fetchAllGroupedBy returning faults, I don't know how to extract the data

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

I see where NSFetchRequest has setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO, and I've seen valueForKey: used, but I can't seem to get it to work with the MR_fetchAllGroupedBy.

I call it with:

```
self.fetchedRC = [FeedSource MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"category" withPredicate:predicate sortedBy:@"category" ascending:YES inContext:self.defaultContext];
```

The configure cell has:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    FeedSource *tempSource = [self.fetchedRC objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    for (int j=0; j<self.tempHeaders.count; j++) {
        FeedSource *myFeedSource = [self.fetchedRC objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if ([self.tempHeaders[j] isEqualToString:tempSource.header]) {
            headerInUse = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
```

MR_fetchAllGoupedBy doesn't have an option (none that I can see) to use fetchRequest, so I can't use setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:.

In the configureCell, tempSource has Null.  As I understand it, I have to trigger the object to get the data and because I'm calling the array, the object doesn't get called to get the data and the array can't get the data.

So, I need to extract the data straight from self.fetchedRC?

How do I do that?

I tried:

```
MLog(@"value for key: %@", [[self.fetchedRC valueForKey:@"category"]allObjects]);
```

it crashes with:
*this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key category.*

I've also tried:

```
FeedSource *myFeedSource = [self.fetchedRC objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *myHeader = myFeedSource.header;
NSString *myNewHeader = [myFeedSource valueForKey:@"header"];
MLog(@"Header: %@",myNewHeader);
MLog(@"Header:%@",myHeader);
```

And they print out Null as well.

UPDATE:
Ok, I changed the code to use the setReturnsObjectsAsFaults and still have faults:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
NSFetchRequest *myFetchRequest = [FeedSource MR_requestAllSortedBy:@"category"
                                            ascending:YES
                                        withPredicate:predicate
                                            inContext:localContext];
[myFetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
[myFetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:30];
NSFetchedResultsController *myFRC = [FeedSource MR_fetchController:myFetchRequest
                                                          delegate:nil
                                                     useFileCache:NO
                                                        groupedBy:@"category"
                                                        inContext:localContext];
[FeedSource MR_performFetch:myFRC];
self.fetchedRC = myFRC;
```

Even the valueForKey is returning null:

```
FeedSource *myFeedSource = [self.fetchedRC objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
MLog(@"[self.fetchedRC objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] %@",[self.fetchedRC objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]);
NSString *myHeader = myFeedSource.header;
NSString *myNewHeader = [myFeedSource valueForKey:@"header"];
MLog(@"Header using valueForKey: %@",myNewHeader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution just in case someone else runs into the same problem:
1. added  NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate to the header
2. added self to delegate in the MR_fetchController call.
3. added - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller method to the .m
Note: the controllerDidChangeContent: method is empty, but seems to have triggered the delegate:self to work.